# Как получить актуальный список всех аудио-файлов через Cursor? (Android)

Tags: java, android, база-данных, файловая-система, contentprovider

Наткнулся на [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480778/how-to-find-all-audio-files-on-sdcard-eclipse-android) этой проблемы через [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), но насколько я понимаю, его состояние нужно обновлять принудительно, т.к. файлы, добавленные через файловый менеджер AVD, не обнаруживаются таким образом до перезагрузки устройства.

- Каким образом можно принудительно обновить состояние сущности [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)?
- Стоит ли свеч такое решение, или оно не лучше рекурсивного обхода всех директорий?